# VLC causes buffer when embedded in Python Tkinter Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc

I have been working on a music player app that uses VLC to play songs directly from the internet and has features like seeking and a progress bar. But as the normal tkinter progress bar looks kinda old so I used `customtkinter.CTkSlider` widget but using this causes buffering. The song plays smoothly on using `Tk.Scale`.

Here, is the code:

```
# import external libraries
import vlc

import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pyautogui
import customtkinter
import pafy

# import standard libraries
import os
from threading import Thread, Event
import time
import platform
import requests

class ttkTimer(Thread):
    """a class serving same function as wxTimer... but there may be better ways to do this
    """
    def __init__(self, callback, tick):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.callback = callback
        self.stopFlag = Event()
        self.tick = tick
        self.iters = 0

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopFlag.wait(self.tick):
            self.iters += 1
            self.callback()

    def stop(self):
        self.stopFlag.set()

    def get(self):
        return self.iters

class Player(Tk.Frame):
    """The main window has to deal with events.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent, title=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        if title == None:
            title = "tk_vlc"
        self.parent.title(title)

        # Menu Bar
        #   File Menu
        menubar = Tk.Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Tk.Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", underline=0, command=self.OnOpen)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=_quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

        # The second panel holds controls
        self.player = None
        self.videopanel = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.canvas = Tk.Canvas(self.videopanel).pack(fill=Tk.BOTH,expand=1)
        self.videopanel.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH,expand=1)

        ctrlpanel = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        pause  = ttk.Button(ctrlpanel, text="Pause", command=self.OnPause)
        play   = ttk.Button(ctrlpanel, text="Play", command=self.OnPlay)
        stop   = ttk.Button(ctrlpanel, text="Stop", command=self.OnStop)
        volume = ttk.Button(ctrlpanel, text="Volume", command=self.OnSetVolume)
        pause.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        play.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        stop.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        volume.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        self.volume_var = Tk.IntVar()
        self.volslider = Tk.Scale(ctrlpanel, variable=self.volume_var, command=self.volume_sel,
                from_=0, to=100, orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL, length=100)
        self.volslider.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        ctrlpanel.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)

        ctrlpanel2 = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        self.scale_var = Tk.DoubleVar()
        self.timeslider_last_val = ""
        self.timeslider = customtkinter.CTkSlider(ctrlpanel2, variable=self.scale_var, command=self.scale_sel,
                from_=0, to=1000, orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL) # This causes buffer
        self.timeslider.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.X,expand=1)
        self.timeslider_last_update = time.time()
        ctrlpanel2.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM,fill=Tk.X)


        # VLC player controls
        self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()

        self.timer = ttkTimer(self.OnTimer, 1.0)
        self.timer.start()
        self.parent.update()

        #self.player.set_hwnd(self.GetHandle()) # for windows, OnOpen does does this

    def Extract(self,topic):
        """Will play video on following topic, takes about 10 to 15 seconds to load"""
        url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?q=' + topic
        count = 0
        cont = ''
        try:
            cont = requests.get(url)
        except:
            print('Error','Cannot Connect.. Internet not connected or invalid URL or id.')
            cont = ''
        data = cont.content
        data = str(data)
        lst = data.split('"')
        for i in lst:
            count+=1
            if i == 'WEB_PAGE_TYPE_WATCH':
                break
        if lst[count-5] == "/results":
            print("Error","No video found.")
        return "https://www.youtube.com"+lst[count-5]

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        """Closes the window.
        """
        self.Close()

    def OnOpen(self):
        """Pop up a new dialow window to choose a file, then play the selected file.
        """
        # if a file is already running, then stop it.
        self.OnStop()

        fullname = pafy.new(self.Extract(pyautogui.password(mask="", title="Enter Song Name:", text="Enter Song Name:"))).getbest().url
        self.Media = self.Instance.media_new(fullname)
        self.player.set_media(self.Media)

            # set the window id where to render VLC's video output
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            self.player.set_hwnd(self.GetHandle())
        else:
            self.player.set_xwindow(self.GetHandle()) # this line messes up windows
            # FIXME: this should be made cross-platform
        self.OnPlay()

            # set the volume slider to the current volume
            #self.volslider.SetValue(self.player.audio_get_volume() / 2)
        self.volslider.set(self.player.audio_get_volume())

    def OnPlay(self):
        """Toggle the status to Play/Pause.
        If no file is loaded, open the dialog window.
        """
        # check if there is a file to play, otherwise open a
        # Tk.FileDialog to select a file
        if not self.player.get_media():
            self.OnOpen()
        else:
            # Try to launch the media, if this fails display an error message
            if self.player.play() == -1:
                self.errorDialog("Unable to play.")

    def GetHandle(self):
        return self.videopanel.winfo_id()

    #def OnPause(self, evt):
    def OnPause(self):
        """Pause the player.
        """
        self.player.pause()

    def OnStop(self):
        """Stop the player.
        """
        self.player.stop()
        # reset the time slider
        self.timeslider.set(0)

    def OnTimer(self):
        """Update the time slider according to the current movie time.
        """
        if self.player == None:
            return
        # since the self.player.get_length can change while playing,
        # re-set the timeslider to the correct range.
        length = self.player.get_length()
        dbl = length * 0.001
        self.timeslider.config(to=dbl)

        # update the time on the slider
        tyme = self.player.get_time()
        if tyme == -1:
            tyme = 0
        dbl = tyme * 0.001
        self.timeslider_last_val = ("%.0f" % dbl) + ".0"
        # don't want to programatically change slider while user is messing with it.
        # wait 2 seconds after user lets go of slider
        if time.time() > (self.timeslider_last_update + 2.0):
            self.timeslider.set(dbl)

    def scale_sel(self, evt):
        if self.player == None:
            return
        nval = self.scale_var.get()
        sval = str(nval)
        if self.timeslider_last_val != sval:
            self.timeslider_last_update = time.time()
            mval = "%.0f" % (nval * 1000)
            self.player.set_time(int(mval)) # expects milliseconds


    def volume_sel(self, evt):
        if self.player == None:
            return
        volume = self.volume_var.get()
        if volume > 100:
            volume = 100
        if self.player.audio_set_volume(volume) == -1:
            self.errorDialog("Failed to set volume")



    def OnToggleVolume(self, evt):
        """Mute/Unmute according to the audio button.
        """
        is_mute = self.player.audio_get_mute()

        self.player.audio_set_mute(not is_mute)
        # update the volume slider;
        # since vlc volume range is in [0, 200],
        # and our volume slider has range [0, 100], just divide by 2.
        self.volume_var.set(self.player.audio_get_volume())

    def OnSetVolume(self):
        """Set the volume according to the volume sider.
        """
        volume = self.volume_var.get()
        # vlc.MediaPlayer.audio_set_volume returns 0 if success, -1 otherwise
        if volume > 100:
            volume = 100
        if self.player.audio_set_volume(volume) == -1:
            self.errorDialog("Failed to set volume")

    def errorDialog(self, errormessage):
        """Display a simple error dialog.
        """
        Tk.tkMessageBox.showerror(self, 'Error', errormessage)

def Tk_get_root():
    if not hasattr(Tk_get_root, "root"): #(1)
        Tk_get_root.root= Tk.Tk()  #initialization call is inside the function
    return Tk_get_root.root

def _quit():
    print("_quit: bye")
    root = Tk_get_root()
    root.quit()     # stops mainloop
    root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent
                    # Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
    os._exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a Tk.App(), which handles the windowing system event loop
    root = Tk_get_root()
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _quit)

    player = Player(root, title="tkinter vlc")
    # show the player window centred and run the application
    root.mainloop()
```

Kindly help
Regards.